# Bash - Filter rows with a certain proportion of columns occupied

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

So, I've got a large number of files, each one with 8 columns and a lot of rows. Here's a head from one of them for an example.

```
ID       Ct       1          2          3          4           5             6
1        0        consensus  -          -          -           -             -
2        0        consensus  -          -          -           -             -
3        0        consensus  consensus  consensus  consensus   consensus     consensus
4        0        consensus  -          consensus  -           -             -
5        0        -          AT         AT         GC          GC            AT
6        0        consensus  -          -          -           consensus     -
7        0        consensus  -          -          -           -             -
8        0        consensus  consensus  consensus  -           consensus     consensus
9        0        consensus  -          -          -           -             -
```

I want to separate out all the rows where the last 6 columns are at least 5/6 occupied. So ID 3, 5 and 8 (row 4, 6 and 9) from my head. So I want all the rows that have less than 2 columns with "-", effectively.

I used to be able to do that with a simple awk script because the program counted how many of the columns were occupied in the second column - seems like I can't do that any more. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Should the header be printed?  Are all files in the same directory?  Do all files have a header?

Comment: Does the file contain tabs or spaces between the columns? (The problem with your `awk` script may depend on that.)

Comment: The files are in separate directories - I've got a shell script to go through each. Header, whichever's easier. All the files have a header and tabs between columns.

Comment: What do you mean by `seems like I can't do that any more`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How far would

```
awk 'gsub(/-/, "&") < 2' file
ID       Ct       1          2          3          4           5             6
3        0        consensus  consensus  consensus  consensus   consensus     consensus
5        0        -          AT         AT         GC          GC            AT
8        0        consensus  consensus  consensus  -           consensus     consensus
```

get you? Be aware that nothing was said rg. the desired output - do you want a single output file, file names prefixed to output lines, or new files with names similar to the original ones, or what?

**EDIT** (after comment on new file names):

```
awk 'gsub(/-/, "&") < 2 {print > (FILENAME ".new")}' /path/to/file/*
```

Comment: New files with similar names to the old one - so that should work if I just pipe that to a new file, right? Seems like that should do the job, thanks!

Comment: Unless you use gawk that will fail after about a dozen output files are created with an error message about too many open files. You should close() them as you go.

Comment: @ Ed Morton: Right, keep an eye on `OPEN_MAX` - which is 1024 on my linux, and /or `kern.maxfilesperproc: 1591` on my FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

If all the files are in the same directory you can use a for loop/glob to loop over each file and run the awk command on them:

```bsh
for file in /path/to/files/*; do
    awk '{
        count=0
        for (i=3;i<=8;i++) {
            if ($i == "-") {
                count++
            }
        }
        if ((count <= 1)) {
            print
        }
    }' "$file"
done
```

For each line, it will loop through columns 3-8, if the value of the column is equal to `-` it adds to `count`, if `count` is greater than 1 for a line it will not be printed.

Comment: A count seems like a good solution - I don't have all the files in the same directory, but I do have a shell script set up to apply the command to all the files. So adding that awk line into that should do nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perl is handy for this kind of thing - in particular, it allows fieldwise `grep` without an explicit loop, the result of which (when evaluated in scalar context) gives a count of matches. So for example

```
$ perl -lane 'print if 3 > grep { $_ eq "-" } splice @F, 2' file
ID       Ct       1          2          3          4           5             6
3        0        consensus  consensus  consensus  consensus   consensus     consensus
5        0        -          AT         AT         GC          GC            AT
8        0        consensus  consensus  consensus  -           consensus     consensus
```